# Load file listed in listbox into rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io

So I'm creating a program where it shows files in a directory and I'm trying to get it so if you click an item inside of it, it loads a files contents (in text) into a rich text box.

```
numberedRTB1.RichTextBox.LoadFile(listBox1.SelectedItem.Name, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: If you have used `DirectoryInfo().GetFiles()`, your `listBox1.SelectedItem` is a `FileInfo` class object. You need to cast the Item to `FileInfo` to access the `.Name` property: `(listBox1.SelectedItem as FileInfo).Name`. You should post all the relevant code so nobody has to guess what objects your are using. As  suggested, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the path of your file you simple can load the text of the file in your RichTextBox by using the `ReadAllText(string path)` method from the [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.7.2) Class
**Small example**

```
richTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText("path/to/file");
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You have failed to actually ask a question.

2) Most likely you want to see the **names without path** in the list but need the **full path** to load them.

For other lists e,g, `ListView` you could use the item's `Tag` but `ListBox` contains either `string` or `object`, neither of which has a `Tag` property.

So do create a `class` with two string fields and a `ToString` method.

Now you see a nice name and can access the full path..

---

Example code for a class:

```
class ListItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FullPath { get; set; }

    public ListItem(string filename, string fullpath )
    { Name = filename; FullPath = fullpath; }

    public ListItem(FileInfo fileinfo )
    { Name = fileinfo.Name; FullPath = fileinfo.FullName; }


    override public string ToString() { return Name; }
}
```

Usage for loading..:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("D:\\test.rtf");
// either..:
listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(fi.Name, fi.FullName));
// or :
listBox1.Items.Add((new ListItem(fi));
```

..and for accessing:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItem item = listBox1.SelectedItem as ListItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        if (File.Exists(item.FullPath) ) rtb.LoadFile(item.FullPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not properly asking a question, I rarely use this site unless I'm really stuck (and typically when I am it's for a stupid reason). But thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: No problem. Did I guess your issue right and did my solution work for you?