# How can I Drag and Drop a File into a listBox and get the FilePath information in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, path, drag-and-drop, listbox

So I want to create a Program which can rename multiple FileNames at once.
I succeed with Java to write such a program, but now switched to C# because I want a Windows App.
Now I want to implement a function where I can just drag files from Windows directly into my listBox and show the FilePaths. But I just started using VS with C# some hours ago and don't know how to do it.

I think, I need to use this method for it, but I don't know any classes in C#
`

```
 private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {}
```

`

Comment: Hans' heavily upvoted answer should get you started. Maybe you want to create a special class to contain a nice short name and also the full path. Add these to the listbox.. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718047/load-file-listed-in-listbox-into-rich-text-box/53724469#53724469) shows an example of a listboxitem class.